# Does Facebook's Graph API Explorer currently not allow for the scraping of visitor posts from a page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to collect visitor posts from the page of a political party. Even though I can collect the statuses posted from the political party itself, when I request a token for visitor_posts, I get the following error message:

{
  "error": {
    "code": 1,
    "message": "Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request"
  }
}

When I then add a limit, I get the same error message, even when I set the limit as 1, 10, or 100. After googling around, people then suggested to add a since/until, since there would be such a high number of visitor posts. However, when I tried that, it also did not work. Has Facebook changed its API to block this kind of collection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check the recent breaking changes?

Comment: _“when I request a token for visitor_posts”_ - what is that supposed to mean? What are the actual requests you are making?

Comment: My end goal is to collect Facebook posts from Facebook users on a political party's Facebook page. So when I say visitor_posts, I mean the posts that Facebook users post on the Facebook page. When I looked into the changes in the Facebook Graph API, I did not find an answer that specifically addresses my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint `[page]/visitor_posts` is still functioning correctly, though there are prerequisites for calling it. Assuming you are a page management app, your access token must have `manage_pages` and `pages_show_list` scopes.

It isn't necessary for you to use a page access token to make this call and the request can be made with a user access token. It's also not necessary to have any permissions or specific roles on the page you are querying.

Since you are having issues with too much data being returned, although including a `limit` didn't help, you may help their query engine out by providing a `since` parameter. This is a filter for posts since a certain unix (seconds) timestamp, example using 12:00 AM UTC today:
`[page]/visitor_posts?since=1523318400`

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I added this 'since' parameter with the time stamp, the code did indeed work. So it is great to know that it is still possible to collect this data. Because I need the data from the last couple of years, I will now just need to figure out how to adjust my code in order to collect past data as well. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem :) You should be able to window over the data and page if needed updating pairs of `from` and `since` params for your windowing.